# Mulesoft Flow processing startegies

Tags: mule

could you please explain Queued-Asynchronous Flow Processing Strategy with an example
i found many documents with the explanation but not getting any example that shows how it to process and flow creation for this

i found one link where it explains synchrounus and non blocking processing strategies

https://www.ricston.com/blog/synchronous-non-blocking-processing-strategies/

Answer (score 0):

The Queued Asynchronous Flow Processing Strategy works by having a thread pool for the message source of the flow (for example a JMS inbound transport), a thread pool for flow execution, and a queue of Mule events between the two threads. So when a JMS message arrives to start the flow, it is handled by a thread of the transport, then it queues in the internal queue as a Mule message, to be picked up by one of the flow threads to execute the rest of the flow. The source threads are freed to keep listening for new messages, that is the 'asynchronous' part. They don't wait for the flow to be processed.